# Apache Solr 6.6.2 configuration update to utilize maximum system resources

Tags: performance, solr, lucene, cpu-usage, solrcloud

I have setup solr 6.x on a dedicated system with 8 cores and 16 GB RAM. There are about 8 Million documents in Solr. Each doc with 20 fields and most fields are both indexed and stored. Following is the plot of last 2 hours CPU usage.

[image]

This plot shows that CPU usage is very minimum. Even if I do stress test, then CPU usage goes to 40-50%. Similar graph is observed in RAM. Now the question is how to configure Solr so that it should use maximum system resources i.e., CPU upto 70-80%.

As I think, it is not fair to ask my boss to provide a new machine when solr performance start to degrade without using max system resources. I know Solr can run in Cloud but my question remains the same, how to use max resources by Solr.

Comment: Quite hard to answer. In what regard is your system slow? Indexing? Is the near real time performance bad? Are queries bad? In general, all queries? Are there certain queries that are worse than others? Did you check your logs (maybe you are logging too much)? Did you already tinker with your solrconfig.xml?

Comment: And do you gather performance statistics? Like described here https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/performance-statistics-reference.html and here https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/metrics-reporting.html

Comment: I am not doing any indexing in real time, rather searching only